# JMeter Recording controller via Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, jmeter

I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04 to record JMeter scenarios.
I can't access HTTPS pages : Firefox return the **SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG** error.

In Firefox, I set up the temporary certificated generated by JMeter, listening to the 8080 port.

When I try to access a HTTPS page, I get this error in the `jmeter.log` file :

```
2019-05-02 16:36:22,461 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy:
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:126) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:988) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:123) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:108) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.writeToClient(Proxy.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:244) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.deliver(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:320) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:983) ~[?:?]
        ... 4 more
2019-05-02 16:36:22,463 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [52392]  Exception when processing sample
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:126) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:988) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:123) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:108) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.writeToClient(Proxy.java:486) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:244) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.deliver(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:320) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:983) ~[?:?]
        ... 4 more
2019-05-02 16:36:22,464 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [52392]  Exception while writing error
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getOutputStream(SSLSocketImpl.java:916) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.writeErrorToClient(Proxy.java:561) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:261) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
```

Is there something I need to adapt in order to access HTTPS pages ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a link which has some methods that you can try:-
https://windowsreport.com/fix-ssl_error_rx_record_too_long-firefox-error/

But, if you have already tried this. Then, try to change the browser to some other like chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You might come across several problems while recording scripts using Jmeter.

I would rather suggest to use [Blazemeter Recording Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) to record your scenarios and then export in .jmx format and modify using jmeter.